# Graphic errors on external monitor connected by DisplayPort-HDMI-Cable

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, colors, external-monitor, displayport

I connected an external monitor to my laptop using a DisplayPort to HDMI Cable (The laptop features only a displayport port) and the colors on the external monitor are skewed and it flickers about once a minute.

I've already tried the following:

- reconnected the cable
- changed the resolution of both monitors
- deactivated all unnecessary settings in the external monitors menu (like Display Data Channel, etc.)
- updated Ubuntu
- reset'ed the external monitors settings

[image: Built-in Monitor]

[image: External Monitor]

What can I try to do to fix the video output?

**Hardware:**

Laptop: HP Elitebook Folio 1040 G2 (with Ubuntu 16.04, Linux 4.4.0-38 x86_64)
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 5550
Ext. Monitor: Acer FHD 21"
Cable: Rankie R1102A 0.9m

`xrandr --verbose`: http://pastebin.com/WFTLxNgc

Comment: xrandr output: http://pastebin.com/WFTLxNgc

Comment: What kernel/ubuntu version you on?

Comment: @Malachi updated question